# Idiomatic `and` & `or` functions (not macros) in Clojure

Tags: clojure, boolean

Strange as it may sound, I am looking for function versions of the [`and`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/and) and [`or`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/or) macros in Clojure.

Why? For one I am curious.

Second, I want to use `or` in [precondition and postcondition](http://clojure.org/special_forms) checks. This does not work:

```
(defn victor
  [x]
  {:post (or (nil? %) (vector %))}
  ;; ...
  )
```

I want the postcondition to check to see if `victor` returns a vector or `nil`, but it fails:

```
#<CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.core/or, compiling:(test/test.clj:10:1)>
```

I don't think `bit-and` and `bit-or` are quite what I'm looking for.

**Update**: This syntax works without an error:

```
(defn victor
  [x]
  {:post [(or (nil? %) (vector %))]}
  ;; ...
  )
```

I'm still curious if functions exist, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the standard method is simply to wrap `and` and `or` in functions, e.g. `(fn [x y] (or x y))`.  In some contexts, another function will work.  For example, a note in the [clojure docs for `and`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/and) suggests using `(every? identity [true false])`. `some`, `not-every?`, and `not-any?` can be used in a similar way.

Answer (score 3):

In general, `and` and `or` functions would be undesirable because they cannot use short-circuiting. Consider the following code:

```
(and false some-expensive-fn)
(or true some-expensive-fn)
```

With `and` and `or` as macros the above code won't execute `some-expensive-fn`, because it is unnecessary to determine the overall truth value of the expression. In function expressions the arguments are evaluated before being passed to the function, but in macros they are not.

Comment: Undesirable? Maybe. Short-circuiting is not necessarily good or bad. It depends on the intent. In any case, this doesn't answer the original question.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question, so I'm downvoting. This only says "what you ask for is undesirable" without giving an answer to the original question. Comment about short-circuiting and side-effects are certainly welcome. A possible answer would be "such functions do not exist" in clojure.core, but such an answer would be incorrect; see Mars' answer.

Comment: From http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/and: "Note `and` is a macro, so you cannot apply it." This is one valid reason to look for a function version.

Answer (score 1):

@Triangle Man is right. Short-circuiting won't work, but nevertheless you can define your own function versions:

```
user=> (defn && [x y] (and x y))
#'user/&&
user=> (&& true false)
false
user=> (&& true true)
true
user=> (defn || [x y] (or x y))
#'user/||
user=> (|| true false)
true
user=> (|| true true)
true
user=> (|| false false)
false
user=>
```